# Magento Chart Skipping Months

Tags: magento

Since upgrading to Magento 1.6.1.0 my charts have been showing data incorrectly.  It seems to skip some months and doesn't show any data for the last few months.  You can see an example in the below image.  I have added the red labels which is what the chart should be showing but you can see that the actual labels skip some months so then becomes inaccurate.  For example the 2 peaks should be November and December 2010 (Christmas) but the chart shows them as December and January.

I am also not seeing any data from August onwards

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Never trust statistics you didn't forge yourself^^. Seriously, this is weird. Does Reports -> Refresh Staticstics help?

Comment: I tried refreshing lifetime stats but no help.  Also, if I run a report it includes all of the correct data so it is just the chart which isn't displaying it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Magento to me. I can see you [already asked](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/266685/) question of official forum, I think you should wait you answer there.

The possible solutions are:

1. wait for some official bugfix or workaround (you should [file a bug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking) if not done that already).
2. rollback to previous version.
3. [fix it youself](http://www.magentocommerce.com/svn) (more theoretical than real, but still possible solution).